# Will my funds return?

Tags: wallet

so after 3 days , my transaction is still unconfirmed , is it possible that my money is gone ? Cause i've read after a week it would be removed from network but i didn't fully understand this .

does this mean my money would go away or it would be back in my wallet ?

Comment: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Fee_bumping#I_sent_the_stuck_transaction

Answer (score 2):

If a transaction is not confirmed, your coins are still in your own "wallet". Money is transferred only when the transaction is confirmed and are part of the blockchain.